# facebook graph api if a user has liked a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use facebook graph api to find out if a user has liked a particular page.This is the query I tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/likes/page_id?access_token="my access token"
```

I tried the same kind of query to find if two users are friends but its returning empty data set even for that.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/frineds/user_id
```

How should I solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
GET /v2.2/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}
```

to find out if a user likes a page. Remember that you need the `user_likes` permission!

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes#readmodifiers

For seeing if a user is a friend of another user, try

```
GET /v2.2/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b}
```

You need the `user_friends` permission to do so.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends#readmodifiers