# Facebook API: how to find if a user liked my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to check, using facebook graph api, if a facebook user has liked a certain page (I am the admin and can grant myself any permission). Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

I can't find it in the docs. The closest in the docs is the following:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/likes/

It says that the request returns: "An array of User or Page objects representing the people or Pages that liked the object" Which is in fact what I am looking for, as I could simply query the user in the list and see if there is a match. **BUT** , in fact, what the request (mentioned above) actually returns is an array of User or Page objects representing the people or Pages that the object (my page) liked.

The request from the docs might sill be implemented to solve the problem:

- [facebook graph api if a user has liked a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309915/facebook-graph-api-if-a-user-has-liked-a-page)

**BUT** it doesn't help me, because I don't want to take the user's permission. I want to implement the solution from the side of the admin of the page- the admin needs to check for multiple users if they liked the page or not.

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: What you want is simply not possible any more. Facebook does not want you to check if users like your specific pages - "like gating" in any way shape or form is not allowed any more. They would not even approve your app's use of the necessary permission in app review for such a purpose, even if you were willing to let users decide whether or not they like you to check for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And do you know for what reason facebook doesn't allow you to view your fans through the api? Because it is rather odd, as it is a functionality that is available from the user interface of facebook- the admin can check who is a fan of the page. Why is a function from the user interface not allowed in the api?

Comment: Because if it was, and you and a thousand other page admins gave the necessary permission to the same app, then whoever controls that app could gather a massiv amount of data of a large user base's preferences without their explicit consent ... and that's already Facebook's own business model.

Comment: If you can do the same thing on Facebook.com then do it there. The reason you ask to do it through the API is that doing it on Facebook.com and through the API is not the same thing.